# Factorize $x+{1\over 2}x^2+{1\over 3}x^3+ \cdot\cdot$ by $1-x$

Tags: polynomials, generating-functions, recursion

I want to derive explicit formula for given recursive relation below:

$$a_{n+1} = (n + 1)a_n + n!$$

for $n ≥ 0$ and $a_0 = 0$.

I had exploited $EGF$, resulting in:

$$g(x)\cdot(1-x) = x+{1\over 2}x^2+{1\over 3}x^3+ \cdot\cdot$$

Thus to derive the explicit formula of $a_n$, I am thinking about how I can manage the $RHS$ to be factorized by $1-x$ so that I can have $a_n$ for corresponding $x^n/n!$

Any advice to proceed further?

I yet haven't took the abstract algebra class where I seemingly guess I could have more chance to be familiar to polynomial series.

Comment: You can multiply by $\sum_{n\ge0}x^n$

Comment: You can just do "polynomial long division", if you're prepared to make believe that that power series is a polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

You can tackle it this way:

$f_n-(n-1)!=nf_{n-1}$

$f_{n-1}-(n-2)!=(n-1)f_{n-2}$

Wraping them togather ...

$f_n-(n-1)!-n(n-2)!=n(n-1)f_{n-2}$

Going same cadence ...

$f_n-(n-1)!-n(n-2)!-n(n-1)(n-3)!=n(n-1)(n-2)f_{n-3}$

You can figure the terminal result on your own from here.

Comment: Also this can be proven by reccurence, and I'm sorry I don't know how this looks because I have latex problems.

Answer (score 1):

We can obtain the numbers $a_n (n\geq 1, a_0=0)$ by calculating the coefficients of the exponential generating function
\begin{align*}
g(x)=a_1x+a_2\frac{x^2}{2!}+a_3\frac{x^3}{3!}+a_4\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots
\end{align*}

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{g(x)}&=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{3}x^3+\frac{1}{4}x^4+\cdots\right)\frac{1}{1-x}\\
> &=\left(x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{1}{3}x^3+\frac{1}{4}x^4+\cdots\right)\left(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=x+\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)x^2+\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\right)x^3
> +\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\right)x^4+\cdots\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_nx^n\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\color{blue}{n!H_n}\frac{x^n}{n!}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}
>
> We conclude the numbers are $$\color{blue}{a_n=n!H_n  \qquad n\geq 1}$$.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*.
- In (2) we multiply the series of the right-hand side and collect the terms with equal powers of $x$. We observe the coefficients are 
  \begin{align*}
  1,\,1+\frac{1}{2},\,1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3},\,1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4},\cdots
  \end{align*}
  which are  the *[harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number)* denoted with $H_n$.
- In (3) we use the sigma notation for brevity.
- In (4) we write the series as exponential generating series to better see the coefficients $a_n$.

> **Note:** If we write the recursion for $a_n$ as
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{a_{n+1}}{(n+1)!}&=\frac{a_n}{n!}+\frac{1}{n+1}\qquad\qquad n\geq 1\\
> a_0&=0
> \end{align*}
>   then the solution $a_n=n!H_n$ might be seen easily.

Comment: What an articulate answer ! I noticed that it's a harmonic sum but the way of estimating this quantity differs.

Comment: @Idle: Thanks for your nice comment. I think both answers provide a helpful contribution to OPs question. :-)